# Smooth scroll to specific div after fixed header

Tags: html, jquery, css

Header - `height` is `100px` with `position static`.

```
.header {
   height: 100px;   
}
```

Means when we scroll down, `header` got `fixed` at the top `position`.

Now what i need is if you `click` on the `button (Click Me!)`, it should `smooth scroll` to the `div with class '.second'`. But due to 100px fixed header the current `jquery` code is not working properly. (`'.second'` is behind the `header`)

```
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="first"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
<div class="second">Hi</div>

$("button").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="first"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
<div class="second">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `position fixed` change to `position: sticky;`
2. for smooth scroll animation
   add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` --> `html`
3. css `scroll-margin-top` - https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-margin-top support > 94%

Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.first,
.second {
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.second {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="first">
  <a href="#second">Click Me!</a>
</div>
<div class="second" id="second">Hi</div>
```